# Bash: execute content of variable including pipe

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

# 1st part
ret=$(ps aux | grep -v grep)    # thats OK 
echo $ret

# 2nd part
cmd="ps aux | grep -v grep"     # a problem with the pipe | 
ret=$($cmd)         
echo $ret
```

How can I use a command-string as I have in the 2nd part? Think the pipe is the problem. Tried to escape it but it did not help. Get some snytax error of ps.

Thanks!

Comment: This is caused by how the order of evaluation works, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385690/linux-command-substitution-order) for example.

Comment: See also [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: (speaking of, how in the world does a FAQ we get asked every week get up to +5?!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `eval` is not recommended here. It can lead to unexpected results, especially when variables can be read from untrusted sources (See [BashFAQ/048 - Eval command and security issues](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

You can solve this in a simple way by defining and calling a function as below

```
ps_cmd() {
    ps aux | grep -v grep
}
```

and use it in the script as

```
output="$(ps_cmd)"
echo "$output"
```

Also a good read would be to see why storing commands in a variable is not a good idea and has a lot of potential pitfalls - [BashFAQ/050 - I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 13):

You need `eval`:

```
ret=$(eval "$cmd")
```

Comment: Note that it's rather hard to get quoting and backslashing right in nested evals; and it's extremely insecure to use eval if parts of the string come from the user.

Comment: Thank you for an actually working answer! now, if you could explain why you can't just do ret=eval $cmd

Comment: @AlRo, first: `ret=eval $cmd` runs `$cmd` with `ret` temporarily set to the string `eval`, and because the `eval` is data there instead of a command, the invocation of `$cmd` is subject to the bugs in [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Second: if you don't quote the `"$cmd"`, then its contents get word-split and glob-expanded _before_ being glued back into a single string and passed to `eval`. The details of exactly how that corrupts your command depends on the details of the command and the files in your current working directory, but it's basically never something good.